# Infinispan support for replicated caches when project versions differ

Tags: caching, wildfly, infinispan

I have a standalone mode cluster on Wildfly 18.1 with Infinispan 9.4.16. When I have the same version of the project on both nodes, replication of cache entries works fine. If, however, I have version A on one node and version B on another node, replication fails with `java.io.InvalidClassException` and `org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: deployment.my-application-versionB.ear.myjar-versionB.jar`. The problem appears to be that node1 running version A is unable to replicate the cache entries from node2 with version B.

Is there a way to fix this? The class being stored in the cache doesn't change and I don't see a reason why Infinispan would be unable to replicate the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the version from the ear that gets deployed. It's not an ideal solution in my opinion but it gets the job done.